# How do you run an extreme bounds analysis with an ordered logistic regression in R?

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I'm trying to run an extreme bounds analysis using an ordered logistic regression (instead of OLS) with Marek Hlavac's ExtremeBounds R package and the `polr` function in the MASS library.

I have a dataset consisting of 3 dependent variables and 18 independent variables with 25 observations. I am trying to determine which of the 18 variables are robustly correlated with each dependent variable by implementing all possible combinations of regressions. So, for the code below I want to run an extreme bounds analysis with Origin (human trafficking score for origin countries) as my dependent variable, GDP per capita as my free variable, and the rest of the variables as doubtful (not including the other two dependent variables).

Here's a subset of my data:

```
head(data)
    Country Transit Destination Origin GDP_Per_Capita_PPP
1 Argentina      NA           3      2          14951.728
2    Belize       1           2   <NA>           7307.061
3    Brazil      NA           1      4          11642.444
4    Canada       3           4      2          37995.005
5     Chile      NA           1      1          15753.963
6  Colombia       1          NA      4           9035.566
  Population Democracy Female_Unemployment Total._Unemployment
1   39289878         8             12.3408             10.0775
2     291329        NA             15.0900              9.3900
3  188167356         8             11.2955              8.6395
4   32571174        10              6.0925              6.3203
5   16354504        10             11.7560              9.0240
6   43200897         7                  NA                  NA
  Female_LF_PR Total_LF_PR Percent_Rural_Pop Gini
1      50.1041     61.7950             9.800 46.7
2           NA          NA            54.704   NA
3      56.8993     67.7640            16.857 55.6
4      61.8830     67.0185            19.787   NA
5      41.3310     56.8750            13.158 47.3
6           NA          NA            23.577   NA
  Percent_phc_ratio Percent_Female_Literacy.rate
1                NA                     98.51077
2                NA                           NA
3                NA                     89.85559
4                NA                           NA
5              29.1                           NA
6                NA                     92.22060
  Percent_total_Literacy_rate Percent_youth_Literacy_rate
1                    98.61080                    99.44608
2                          NA                          NA
3                    89.61523                    97.58230
4                          NA                          NA
5                          NA                          NA
6                    92.29968                    97.88317
  Fertility_rate Percent_Pop_0.14 Population_density
1         2.3970         27.06570          14.356715
2         2.9800         38.25984          12.771986
3         1.9250         26.82929          22.513066
4         1.5862         17.40098           3.581804
5         1.9010         24.11969          21.995695
6         2.1980         29.79432          38.937266
  Percent_Employment_agri Trade_._of_GDP
1                   1.051       40.43348
2                  19.484      123.52556
3                  15.618       26.04170
4                   2.112       68.25132
5                  12.849       73.09865
6                  19.963       39.64136
```

And here's the code I'm trying to run:

```
library(MASS)
library(ExtremeBounds)

data$Origin <- ordered(as.factor(data$Origin))
data$GDP_Per_Capita_PPP = scale(data$GDP_Per_Capita_PPP)
data$Population = scale(data$Population)

doubtful_vars <- c("Population","Democracy","Female_Unemployment","Total._Unemployment","Female_LF_PR","Total_LF_PR","Percent_Rural_Pop","Gini","Percent_phc_ratio", "Percent_Female_Literacy.rate","Percent_total_Literacy_rate","Percent_youth_Literacy_rate","Fertility_rate","Percent_Pop_0.14","Population_density","Percent_Employment_agri","Trade_._of_GDP")

origin_eba <- eba(data = data, y = "Origin", free = "GDP_Per_Capita_PPP", doubtful = doubtful_vars, reg.fun = polr, na.action = na.omit, method = "logistic", Hess = TRUE)
```

Which results in this error:

> Error in optim(s0, fmin, gmin, method = "BFGS", ...) :
> initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite
> In addition: Warning message:
> glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

I'm not sure what it means or how to resolve it. I'm somewhat new to R, so if anyone knows the correct way to do this analysis please let me know. Thank you!